# Differences between purpose of ListView and TableView

Tags: java, android, user-interface, listview, tablelayout

I've something like 10-30 object and every object have some datas(about 10) like , age, birthday and ...

I want to show all of them in a list , but I don't know TableLayout is made for what I want to do or ListView ?
What are differences between them and pros and cons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your list items are fixed and limited then you can simply use `TableLayout` and `ScrollView` (to scroll in small devices). For this you need to do extra work programmatically. But `ListView` is a view which groups several similar items and display them in vertical scrollable list. The list items are automatically inserted to the list using an adapter(`BaseAdapter`). Less strain when compared in development wise as well as it will improve the performance by using already created Views (with ViewHolder design pattern)

**EDIT :**

As you said there is much data in one item. So first of all

- draw on paper how each item should display.
- then create a layout xml file. use best fit Layout (`RelativeLayout` mostly)
- assign the id's for each View .
- inflate the layout in `getView` method of your `BaseAdapter` subclass.

for guide you can refer [this](http://javapapers.com/android/android-cards-list-view/)

Comment: My items are not fixed but my problem is I have many data for each item and it's not so beautiful ... Can you show me any idea of putting many datas in each ListView item.

Answer (score 0):

Use ListView with [custom adaptor](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/) . so you can design your list view row as you want to meet design aspects.